# Confusion on the use of callbacks in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and as far as I understood callback function is a function that is executed after another function finished executing. Then, how the callback functions work in forEach, setTimeOut and addEventListener. Does the callback function executes after another function in those functions. I mean does the definition of callback I wrote above is applicable to the use of callback function in forEach, setTimeOut and addEventListener.

Comment: [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) It helps to read documentation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, Patrick thank you for your comments. What confuses me is that does the use of callback in forEach, setTimeOut and addEventListener satisfies the definition of callback function is a function that is executed after another function finished executing. I hope for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am new to JavaScript and as far as I understood callback function is a function that is executed after another function finished executing.

You misunderstand.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function):

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

There's no requirement for the callback to be invoked only after something has finished.

`forEach`, `setTimeOut` and `addEventListener` call the callback whenever doing so meets with the logic of what they are supposed to do. e.g. every time the event fires in the case of `addEventListener`

Comment: thank you for your kind explanation, so, can I imagine it like this: synchronous callback is to help to another function to perform action, asynchronous callback is to execute function after another function completed executing:)

Comment: @MMMMMM — No. `addEventListener` callbacks are asynchronous and trigger in response to events (potentially multiple times), not the completion of some other function.